# How to zoom Kinect camera?

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect

I am now starting my own voyage into the realms of the kinect development. Is there any support for  zooming the camera using the c# sdk?

Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this thread [there is no support for zoom other than digital zoom](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/d35c5f6e-342d-4b38-927a-31a9de37f91c)

You could have a look at the, [not officially endorsed](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/310675/ms-warns-against-kinect-zoom-modification/), hardware add-on for Kinect by Nyko: [Zoom](http://nyko.com/products/product-detail/?name=Zoom)

Comment: @Tigran - what do you mean to say?

Comment: I mean Nyko Zoom, didn't listen before

Comment: @Tigran - ah you mean you hadn't heard of it before? Sorry