# Any way to physically move the Kinect camera?

Tags: kinect

Really new to kinect. I am trying to read up material I find. I found technical spec and the .net API documentation, but could figure out if what I am trying to do is possible:

Can I instruct the kinect to physically move the cameras? (I want to view other people in the room for example).

Edited: I am using the MS Kinect SDK.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the MS Kinect SDK or some third party API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NuiCamera.ElevationAngle to set the elevation angle of kinect camera. Yea, as mentioned above answer, you can only move up and down.

This is the example in Visual C#

I create a slider to get the value. Kinect Mortor is limited to -27 to 27 degree of rotation only.

```
 <Slider Value = "{Binding ElevationAngle, Mode =TwoWay}" Height="171" Interval="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Margin="914,536,284,45" Maximum="27" Minimum="-27" Name="slider_tilt" Orientation="Vertical" SmallChange="1" TickPlacement="TopLeft" Width="38" />
```

Create a button called btnSetTilt and under the button click event, feed the value of slider to Elevation angle. That's it.

```
    private void btnSetTilt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          //Set angle to slider_tilt value
       nui.NuiCamera.ElevationAngle = (int)slider_tilt.Value; 


    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) you can control it with

```
public setMotorPosition(float)
```

With the [Microsoft Kinect SDK for Windows](http://kinectforwindows.org) you can use

```
NuiCameraSetElevation
```

which is limited to 1 call per second and no more than 15 calls per 20 second period.

The motor and gear are not meant for frequent use.

Comment: thank you. Following this question since I've gotten your attention. Is it possible to zoom the kinect camera? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284284/how-to-zoom-kinect-camera/8284369#8284369

Comment: I thought perhaps you knew of another open source solution.

Comment: No. iFixit has a teardown of Kinekt which should give hints about the physical capabilities. http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Microsoft-Kinect-Teardown/4066/1

Answer (score 1):

You can but only up and down, it wont work moving side to side. And Roger Lindsjo has the same explanation as I do. But just wanted to clarify.